# How can I control/refer to UIViews from other UIViews with the same parent?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, swift3, uiviewcontroller

I am currently building an application with a single `UIScrollView` on the page, which will have 3 `UIViews` in it. The three `UIViews` are `leftPanel`, `centerPanel` and `rightPanel`. `leftPanel` occupies 30% of the screen width, `centerPanel` occupies 70% of the screen width and `rightPanel` occupies 30% of the screen width. By default, `leftPanel` and `centerPanel` are shown, and when the user swipes from right to left, the `leftPanel` moves out from the left, and the `rightPanel` moves in from the right. The center panel moves in from the right side to the left. So `leftPanel`, `centerPanel` and `rightPanel` all have the same super view, which is the `UIScrollView` on the screen. I intend to have a button inside `rightView`, which on clicking, will make a `UIImageView` in the centerPanel appear at the bottom. How can I control the `centerPanel` from actions on the `UIButton` in the `rightPanel`?

**My implementation of the UIScrollView uses:**

```
self.addSubview(leftPanel)
self.addSubview(centerPanel)
self.addSubview(rightPanel)
```

to add the three subviews to the scrollView.
I can use the `super` keyword to get the superview of the `rightPanel`, the UIScrollView, but how can I access the `centerPanel` from there?
If I can save the reference to the UIView in a variable called `centerPanelAccess` I intend to do something like:

```
var centerPanelAccess = /* link to the centerPanel */
var imageView = /* The UIImageView to add */
centerPanelAccess.addSubview(imageView)
```

**Here is what I have tried to do so far:**

```
centerPanel.addSubView(imageView) /* Error: Instance member 'addSubview' cannot be used on type 'UIView'; did you mean to use a value of this type instead?*/
```

From the above, I think that I need to refer to the specific instance of `centerPanel` that my code was using, so I tried this, to refer specifically to that instance:

```
super.centerPanel.addSubView(imageView) /* Value of type 'UIView' has no member centerPanel */
```

From this attempt, I realised that there was no variable in the `UIScrollView` which actually allowed me to refer to the `centerPanel`.

**Please can you suggest how I can refer to the instance of the `centerPanel` in the `UIScrollView` from inside the code in the `UIView` class of `rightPanel`?**

**EDIT:** As it seems that accessing and operating on views from within other views is not advisable, is there any way around the problem?

Comment: You can use a delegation pattern, probably from your button handler in the right view to the view controller that is responsible for your scroll view.  This view controller can then call the method on the center panel

Comment: Thank you for the response. Can you guide me to a sample of how I can implement this? Also, please can you explain how this works?

Comment: Also, would it be possible to implement such a method from within the `rightPanel` code itself? @Paulw11

Comment: I wouldn't do that; you don't want views communicating with each other; that is the view controller's job

Comment: @Paulw11 Thank you for informing me on that. Can you show me a sample of how I could implement it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

View's should not communicate directly.  The view controller should co-ordinate activities between the views.  This view controller should already have a reference to the `left`, `center` and `right` views.

You can create a protocol so that the `right` view can notify the view controller that the button was tapped:

```
protocol RightViewDelegate {
    func buttonWasTapped()
}
```

Then your `RightView` can support a delegate of this type:

```
class RightView: UIView {

     var delegate: RightViewDelegate?

     @IBAction buttonHandler(_ sender: UIButton) {
         self.delegate?.buttonWasTapped()
}
```

In your `ViewController` you set the delegate and handle the button tap in the delegate method by calling the method to add the new in the center view:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, RightViewDelegate {

    var leftView: LeftView!
    var rightView: RightView!
    var centerView: CenterView!

    func viewDidLoad {
        super.viewDidLoad()

     // After you set your views into your scroll view:
        self.rightView.delegate = self
    }


    func buttonWasTapped() {
        self.centerView.addView()
    }
}
```

Comment: Alright. Is there nothing for the `UIScrollView` to do? The UIScrollView is the part having the `leftPanel`, `centerPanel` and `rightPanel` as its subviews.

Comment: The scroll view is just a view, so it doesn't do anything. The scrollview is managed by a view controller. That is where you build your logic.

Answer (score -2):

When you make these subview you could give them some unique tags like:

```
leftPanel.tag = 111
centerPanel.tag = 222
rightPanel.tag = 333
```

Then in your rightView class you could get the center panel using the tag

```
var centerPanelAccess:UIView = self.superview.viewWithTag(222) as! UIView
```

Here self point to the rightView, so the superview object will give you the scrollView in which rightView is added. Once you have scrollView then you can get its centerpanel with viewWithTag() method. Hope you got it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried doing what you wrote in my code, however, it still doesn't work. It gives me the following error message:
`Instance member 'tag' cannot be used on leftPanel`

Comment: This is not a correct approach. Use suggested delegation pattern. I would call this dirty hack.

Comment: Here is what I wrote:
`self.addSubview(leftPanel)`
        `self.addSubview(centerPanel)`
        `self.addSubview(rightPanel)`
        `leftPanel.tag = 111`
        `centerPanel.tag = 222`
        `rightPanel.tag = 333`